# Como se usa una funcion en una vista? Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Alguien sabe por que no puedo usar el metodo 'people_by_category()' de un controlador en una vista de laravel? 
Antes se podia ahora no encuentro la forma de hacerlo.

Este es el script que tengo en una vista cualquiera:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown();
        $('.sidenav').sidenav();
        $('select').formSelect();
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
        });
        $('#categorias').on('change', function(){
            alert({{route('people-by-category')}});
        });
    });
    </script>
```

esta es la ruta:

```
Route::get('/people-by-category', 'StaffController@people_by_category')->name('people-by-category');
```

y este es el metodo:

```
    public function people_by_category(){
        return 'prrroooss';
    }
```

Comment: Explícanos eso que antes se podía, ¿qué podías hacer antes y ahora no?

Comment: el metodo devuelve una cadena, quiero mostrar esa cadena llamando al metodo desde la vista. En realidad no encuentro la forma de llamar a cualquier metodo desde la vista. Este es solo un ejemplo rapido

Answer (score 1):

Laravel funciona con la Arquitectura REST, es por eso que no puedes imprimir el contenido de una función sin antes haber realizado una petición HTTP, en tu caso como quieres imprimir en la vista te tendrás que ayudar con AJAX para realizar la petición a la ruta del método indicando su verbo asociado, que por lo que muestras en el código ejemplo es GET. El código quedaría de la siguiente manera para que pueda funcionar:

```
$('#categorias').on('change', function(){
     $.get("{{route('people-by-category')}}", function(data) {
         alert(data);
     });
});
```

Comment: nada, me escribe la direccion de la ruta en la pantalla

Comment: Respuesta editada